# Deploying visual studio Load Test project to a server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-loadtest

Using visual studio enterprise edition 2019. I am able to run load test by using the load test editor.

Is it possible to deploy this solution to a server and kick off load test from that server without having visual studio installed in that server?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as to trigger load test, that machine should have vstest.console.exe file which is part of Visual studio load test installer.